# Put a fill color in a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel, colors, fill

My program loops through each row of data in a sheet. Then when it errors, I want to put a fill color on that specific cell.

Is there a way to put a fill color in a cell without using Range?

```
 On Error GoTo Stop

  'doing something

 Exit Sub
Stop:
Msgbox("Error!")

'something like this to fill the cell
Sheets("Data").Cells(rowdata,1).Color = red
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
Cells(rowindex, columnindex).interior.color = RGB-code

cells(rowindex, columnindex).interior.colorindex = indexno
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @psychicebola. Appreciate your help.